# Angular 2 ng object in prodmode

Tags: angular

Is there a way to access the `ng` object after I enabled prodmode via:

`enableProdMode();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported.

`prodMode` is an performance optimized mode where debugging "stuff" is not included.

It might be possible to pass a `CompilerConfig` that returns `true` for `genDebugInfo()` even when `isDevMode()` returns `false`

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/60b10134df1c1bd15229b999e327fb3c29f16483/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/config.ts#L41

I just assumed that `genDebugInfo()` enables/disable `ng` but haven't checked closer.